# In a JSP file, how do I prevent textarea from being cleared with a form submit?

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I am a newbie so I may doing something totally wrong.  I am using want to use a JSP file because I am doing lots of processing of the data and I am comfortable with Java.

I want to have a form with text and textareas where the user can click a submit button and see intermediate results without clearing the values they have entered.  I have figured out how to do this with the text by setting the value in the HTML section but the textarea is always cleared.

I do not think textareas have the value attribute like text and request.setAttribute() did not work.

Here is an abridged version of my test.jsp code:

```
<html><body>
<form method="post" action="test.jsp">
    Enter your name: 
    <input type="text" size="20" name="txtName" value="<%= request.getParameter("txtName") %>"  />
    <br>
    Enter Sentence:<textarea name="sentence"  ></textarea>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="B1" value="Submit" />
</form>

<%
    String name = request.getParameter("txtName");
    if(name != null){
        out.println("Name: " + name + "<br>");
    }

    String str = request.getParameter("sentence");
    if(str != null){
        if(!str.equals(""))
            out.println("Sentence entered: " + str);
            // This does not work properly
            request.setAttribute("sentence", str);
    }
%>

</body></html>
```

When I click the Submit button, I display the name and sentence but the textarea is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit the value of a textarea using javascript: first set an ID to the textarea, for example "textarea". Then save the content of the textarea in a variable and write it into the textarea after entering a button:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = textareaValue;
```

If you use single buttons without a form, the page doesn't need to be loaded again, and I guess the content of the textarea is not influenced. Example:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="showResults()" value="Show results" />
```

Comment: You said "using javascript" and I do not know how to use javascript in the jsp file.  I added the line "document.getElementById("sentenceId").innerHTML = str;" into the Java part of my code but it says the variable "document cannot be resolved" which makes sense to me because I have not declared document anywhere.  As I said I am a newbie and not sure what I am doing.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out how to add javascript within the jsp and it works.  I cannot answer my own question for 10 hours but here are the lines that worked.  %> <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("sentenceId").innerHTML = "<%=str%>";</script> <%

Answer (score 0):

I believe the quickest way closest to your current approach would be to add the request parameter between the textarea tag, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="test.jsp">
    Enter your name:
    <input type="text" size="20" name="txtName" value="<%= request.getParameter("txtName") %>"  />
    <br>
    Enter Sentence:<textarea name="sentence"  ><%= request.getParameter("sentence") %></textarea>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="B1" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aloso,

Thanks.  I figured out how to add javascript within the jsp and it works.

For anyone else who has the problem, here is code that works:

```
<html><body>
<form method="post" action="test.jsp">
    Enter your name: 
    <input type="text" size="20" name="txtName" value="<%= request.getParameter("txtName") %>"  />
    <br>
    Enter Sentence:<textarea name="sentence" id="sentenceId" ></textarea>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="B1" value="Submit" />
</form>

<%
    String name = request.getParameter("txtName");
    if(name != null){
        out.println("Name: " + name + "<br>");
    }

    String str = request.getParameter("sentence");
%>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("sentenceId").innerHTML = "<%=str%>";</script>

<%
    //document.getElementById("sentenceId").innerHTML = str;
    if(str != null){
        if(!str.equals(""))
            out.println("Sentence entered: " + str);
            // This does not work properly
            //request.setAttribute("sentence", str);
    }
%>

</body></html>
```

The important line is:

```
    %>  <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("sentenceId").innerHTML = "<%=str%>";</script>   <%
```